# Not all exceptions catched within the error handler

Tags: symfony, exception, silex

Consider a Silex application with error handling:

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $exception, $code) use ($app, $locale) {
    die($exception->getMessage());    
});
```

For login purpose, an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is defined:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        ...

        if ($somethingWrong) {
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

The `AuthenticationException` is not catched within the error handler.

Yet, throwing `\RuntimeException` or `\Exception` will be catched by the handler.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably means that `AuthenticationException` has been catched and handled already beetween `onAuthenticationSuccess` and your closure, doesn't it?

Comment: True, even more given that `AuthenticationException` actually extends `\RuntimeException`

Comment: Definitely. But what confuses me is that others exceptions behave the same such as `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException` for instance. If I can't rely on these to abort execution, maybe should I write and throw my own exceptions?

Comment: That's the matter of architecture of your application and the goals you want to archive. If you want to catch the exception in only one point and prevent them being caught in other places - of course, you need your custom Exception class. If you want them to be treated as a usual `AuthenticationException` use this class or extend it.